# Time calculation software for Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

how can I display the time of calculation of any software operation?
For example:

```
seq 1 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$ time seq 1 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
15

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: You can always execute it in a subshell using `time (seq 1 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}')`

Answer (score 1):

Just prepend `time`:

```
time seq 1 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

Output:

```
15

real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.076s
sys     0m0.030s
```

Comment: HA, my machine is faster than yours :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl: I am on cygwin ATM :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`time`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29) command:

```
$ time seq 1 5 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Time is a complex entity, with many possible answers. Do you want the amount of time the CPU was blocked? The amount of time the process was alive? The amount of time the user had to wait for an answer? Or some other meaning of *time* altogether.

Usually you can get what you need from the POSIX [time](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html) utility.

```
time { seq 1 5 | awk … }

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.003s
```

**real** is the total time elapsed.

**user** is the amount of CPU time spent outside the kernel. (User mode CPU time.)

**sys** is the amount of CPU time spent within the kernel.

There is a more complete explanation at [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1)