# Python loop speed sources

Tags: python, performance, list, if-statement, append

Lets say I have a input with 10 million lines.
I want to know how long it takes to do this:

```
if line not in list:
  list.append(line)
```

Is there any website or source of another kind that can tell me the approximate speed of various tasks?

Comment: Have you tried `timeit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the total running time of your program with this:

```
time python3 program.py
```

in your terminal. It will have output similar to:

```
real    0m0.184s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.015s
```

---

You can get how long it takes a particular function to run `n` times with:

```
from timeit import timeit

def foo():
    return 123456789 + 987654321

n = 10000000
time = timeit(foo, number=n)
print(time)
```

---

You can also time how long a section of code takes with `time`:

```
from time import time

start = time()

# code to be timed

finish = time()
print(finish - start)
```

Comment: Explain the print statement in timeit

Comment: @AWE I simplified it.

Comment: And the answer is in seconds?

Answer (score 1):

run this command on terminal :

```
time python your_file.py
```

result must be like this :

```
real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.009s
```

that

```
real - refers to the actual elasped time 
user - refers to the amount of cpu time spent outside of kernel
sys - refers to the amount of cpu time spent inside kernel specific functions
```

read more about `real`,`user`,`sys` in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556411/2867928) stachoverflow answer by ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells.

For find performance of ech line you must use a Line-by-line timing and execution frequency with a profiler, so `line_profiler` is an easy and unobtrusive way to profile your code and use to see how fast and how often each line of code is running in your scripts. you can install [line_profiler](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/) that written by Robert Kern , you can install the python package via pip :

```
$ pip install line_profiler
```

read documentation [HERE](http://www.appneta.com/blog/line-profiler-python/) .