# Increased occupancy without speedup in FFT

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, scipy, fft

### Problem

I have to compute many Fourier transforms.  I would like to do these in parallel with my many cores.  Note that I don't want a parallel FFT algorithm, I just want to launch many embarrassingly parallel FFTs.

I discover that, while my CPU usage goes up, my time to completion does not decrease.

### Example

We create some random data

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.random.random(10000000)  # some random data
```

And time how long it takes to compute an FFT both cold and after having computed it once.

```
In [3]: %time _ = np.fft.rfft(x)        # cost of one run
CPU times: user 589 ms, sys: 23.9 ms, total: 612 ms
Wall time: 613 ms

In [4]: %time _ = np.fft.rfft(x)        # there is some speedup from mulitple runs
CPU times: user 365 ms, sys: 12.4 ms, total: 378 ms
Wall time: 381 ms
```

We run this on a sequence of data sequentially

```
In [5]: %time _ = map(np.fft.rfft, [x] * 12)  # many runs sequentially
CPU times: user 4.4 s, sys: 135 ms, total: 4.54 s
Wall time: 4.54 s

In [6]: 4.54 / 12                       # Same cost per FFT
Out[6]: 0.37833333333333335
```

We do the same thing but now using a thread pool of four threads.

```
In [7]: from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

In [8]: pool = ThreadPool(4)            # I have four physical cores

In [9]: %time _ = pool.map(np.fft.rfft, [x] * 12)
CPU times: user 15.5 s, sys: 1.3 s, total: 16.8 s
Wall time: 4.79 s
```

We find that there is no speedup.  However we do find that CPU usage, as measured by `top`, is near 400%.  This isn't an issue with the GIL.  There is something about FFT that doesn't parallelize well.  Perhaps we're thrashing higher level caches?

**Hardware:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz

### Question

Generally what's going on here and is there a way to leverage multiple cores to speed up multiple FFTs in parallel?

Comment: What's your hardware?

Comment: @MaxHutchinson, does not seem to be hardware related. See this here as well.

Comment: @cel but I do see a speedup on my workstation hardware.  FFT is all memory system, so on under-powered machines, I could imagine a single thread being able to saturate memory capabilities.

Comment: @MaxHutchinson an old personal notebook.  Not a nice workstation.  Added details in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my workstation, ThreadPool **does** provide a speed-up (though not a perfect one):

```
In [42]: x = np.random.random(2**23)

In [43]: %time _ = list(map(np.fft.rfft, [x]*12))
CPU times: user 3.32 s, sys: 380 ms, total: 3.7 s
Wall time: 3.7 s

In [44]: tpool = ThreadPool(4)

In [45]: %time _ = list(tpool.map(np.fft.rfft, [x]*12))
CPU times: user 5.4 s, sys: 596 ms, total: 6 s
Wall time: 1.62 s

In [46]: 3.7/4
Out[46]: 0.925
```

I'm using Python3, so maybe there is something there?  Otherwise, its likely hardware.  FFTs are memory-bound, so its quite possible that a single thread is saturating your memory system.  You might be able to get better memory system locality by dropping down to an environment that let's you control affinity.

#### Hardware

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4930K CPU @ 3.40GHz.

Comment: So does "waiting for memory transfer" count towards CPU usage as measured by system utilities?

Comment: @MRocklin : probably?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1