# Time to execute script file with psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a script file with several SQL statements in it. I know how to get the time to execute each statement. I am running it with the `\i` option from inside of `psql`. Is there a way to get or print the total time for the file? In other words, the combined time?

Using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: temp var to add them ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bash` friendly environment:

```
$ time psql <<connection settings>> < script.sql
```

Sample output:

```
$ time sleep 3

real    0m3.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

You are interested in "real" value. More on these values: [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1/556411#556411)