# How can I measure execution time of a Python program (functional structure)?

Tags: python, function, time

I need to measure the execution time of a Python program having the following structure:

```
import numpy
import pandas

def func1():
    code

def func2():
    code

if __name__ == '__main__':

    func1()
    func2()
```

If I want to use "time.time()", where should I put them in the code? I want to get the execution time for the whole program.

Alternative 1:

```
import time
start = time.time() 

import numpy
import pandas

def func1():
    code

def func2():
    code


if __name__ == '__main__':

    func1()
    func2()


end = time.time()
print("The execution time is", end - start)
```

Alternative 2:

```
import numpy
import pandas

def func1():
    code

def func2():
    code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    start = time.time() 

    func1()
    func2()

    end = time.time()
    print("The execution time is", end - start)
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux: you could run this file test.py using the time command

> time python3 test.py

After your program runs it will give you the following output:

real    0m0.074s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1) will tell the difference between the three times you get

Answer (score -1):

The whole program:

```
import time
t1 = time.time() 

import numpy
import pandas

def func1():
    code

def func2():
    code

if __name__ == '__main__':

    func1()
    func2()

t2 = time.time()
print("The execution time is", t2 - t1)
```

Comment: How is it different from OP's post?