# What is the "time" mean in the command line arguement "time node app.js"?

Tags: bash

App.js contains this code:

```
function add(num1,num2){
    let sum = num1+ num2;
}
let sum = add(2,2);
```

When I run "time node app.js" In the command line I get the response:

real    0m0.312s

user    0m0.000s

sys     0m0.015s

What does this mean? What is the time flag measuring? How is the runtime calculated? Can you point me to documentation on this flag?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines

Answer (score 0):

`time` is a unix command used to determine the duration of execution of a particular command. When run with your node command you will see something like

```
1.88 real         0.24 user         0.06 sys
```

at the end of the execution. `real` is the total elapsed time, `user` is the time spent in user code and `sys` is time spent in lernel code. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556411/7836976)  explains it much better.