# Python multiprocessing: How to measure runtime of a subprocess in a worker?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Let `work_one()` be a function like this:

```
def work_one(program_path):
    task = subprocess.Popen("./" + program_path, shell=True)
    t = 0
    while True:
        ret = task.poll()
        if ret != None or t >= T: # T is the max time we allow for 'task'
            break;
        else:
            t += 0.05
            time.sleep(0.05)
    return t
```

There are many such programs to feed to `work_one()`. When these programs run sequentially, the time reported by each `work_one()` is a reliable coarse measure of each program's runtime.

---

However, let say we have a `multiprocessing.Pool()` instance comprising 20 workers, `pool`, and we call function like this:

```
   def work_all(programs):
       pool = multiprocessing.Pool(20)
       ts = pool.map(work_one, programs)
       return ts
```

Now, the runtime measures reported by `work_all()` is approximately 20 times larger than what a sequential `work_one()` would have reported.

This is reasonable, because inside `work_one()`, when a worker's process adds `0.05` to `t` and yields (by calling `time.sleep()`), it might not be able to yield to the subprocess it is managing (`task`) (**unlike** when there is only one worker); instead, the OS might decided to give the CPU to another concurrent worker's process. Therefore the number of iterations inside a `worker_one()` may be 20 times more before `task` completes.

Question:

1. How to correctly implement `work_one()` to get a good runtime measure, knowing that `work_one()` might be running concurrently?
2. I also want `work_one()` to return early if the subprocess `task` doesn't complete in `T` seconds, so `os.wait*()` functions seems not a good solution because they block the parent process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several relevant times for a process; here's how to get them all (see [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1); tl;dr: total time CPU was engaged on your process is `user_time + system_time`):

```
import time
import os
import subprocess

def work_one(program_path):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    task = subprocess.Popen(program_path, shell=True)
    pid, exit_status, resource_usage = os.wait4(task.pid, 0)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    real_time = end - start
    user_time = resource_usage.ru_utime
    system_time = resource_usage.ru_stime
    return (real_time, user_time, system_time)
```

EDIT: Modified to provide timeout. However, I couldn't make `resource.getrusage` return anything but zeroes on my test cases; maybe it needs a longer process, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutError()

timeout = 2

def work_one(program_path):
    try:
        timed_out = False
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
        signal.alarm(timeout)
        start = time.perf_counter()
        task = subprocess.Popen(program_path, shell=True)
        pid, exit_status, resource_usage = os.wait4(task.pid, 0)
    except TimeoutError:
        timed_out = True
        resource_usage = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
        os.kill(task.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    real_time = end - start
    user_time = resource_usage.ru_utime
    system_time = resource_usage.ru_stime
    return (timed_out, real_time, user_time, system_time)
```

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot to add the important part: I also want `work_one()` to return early if the subprocess `task` doesn't complete in `T` seconds.. I'll modify the question. Except this, this is a very good answer!