# Timelimit plays for twice the duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following command to stream to a test an endpoint:

```sh
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -f lavfi -re -i testsrc=size=hd720:rate=30 
       -f lavfi -re -i anoisesrc 
       -vf "drawtext=fontfile=\'/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf\': text=\'Local time %{localtime\: %Y\/%m\/%d %H.%M.%S} (%{n})\': x=50: y=50: fontsize=48: fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" 
       -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -g 30 -profile:v baseline -preset veryfast 
       -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k -timelimit 60 -f flv $RTMP_OUTPUT/$NAME
```

Because I'm adding this command to my automation, I would like to protect it from running indefinitely in case something goes wrong with my script (I start the ffmpeg job in a background process that is detached from the script). Therefore, I added the flag `-timelimit 60`, that, according to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options), the job should exit after *duration* seconds.

I can see that the command is being parsed correctly

```sh
Reading option '-timelimit' ... matched as option 'timelimit' (set max runtime in seconds) with argument '60'.
...
Finished splitting the commandline.
...
Applying option timelimit (set max runtime in seconds) with argument 60.
...
```

Here's an example output

[image]

The issue is that I noticed that the stream runs for longer than the specified time. After a couple of tests, I noticed that it is running for double the time, which got me thinking if it is taking the number of frames (assuming 2-second frames).

Can someone clarify the `timelimit` option, please? And the possible causes for running longer than specified.

PS: I'm using ffmpeg version 4.1.4 on a MAC OS Mojave (10.14.6)

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: This output was with timelimit equals to 10 seconds
https://gist.github.com/qa-basher/c2262e52b70dcc84bc5c0d50062cd4a6#file-ffmpeg-txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-timelimit` uses user/utime. Not real/rtime/wall-clock time, nor is it directly related to the input file frame rate or duration. You can confirm this by adding the `-benchmark` global option which logs time info to the console output:

```
bench: utime=59.575s stime=1.273s rtime=105.475s
```

See [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1)