# perf stat time elapsed for sys and user

Tags: linux, pthreads, profiling, cpu-usage, perf

Here is my question:
`perf stat` will show some info for program running.
Below is my program running on a Linux system with Intel 32 cores, my program have 32 threads.

```
Performance counter stats for './mul8_t32_lock/dfc_main':

     2,527,620.62 msec task-clock                #   27.051 CPUs utilized
        5,382,455      context-switches          #    0.002 M/sec
          322,153      cpu-migrations            #    0.127 K/sec
        6,728,473      page-faults               #    0.003 M/sec
5,773,817,446,711      cycles                    #    2.284 GHz
8,504,327,916,051      instructions              #    1.47  insn per cycle
  358,700,135,637      branches                  #  141.912 M/sec
      952,042,974      branch-misses             #    0.27% of all branches

     93.438474548 seconds time elapsed

   2482.333923000 seconds user
     66.839344000 seconds sys
```

So, why is the `seconds user` + `seconds sys` do not equal `seconds time elapsed`?
And, I want to know the real meaning of the `seconds user` and `seconds sys`.

Comment: Look how many cores your code used on average: `27.051 CPUs utilized`.  That lets it use more than 1 CPU-second of cpu time in 1 second of wall-clock time.

Comment: [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734965) explains that user+sys can exceed elapsed on multi-threaded machines.  Other answers have more detail on other things. Looks like an exact duplicate because `perf stat` is simply reporting the same process-accounting times as `time` does.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks guy, I begin understand about this confused concept.